# Configurable 'swapping' order of loops

Tags: delphi

The code below groups a list by either number or letter, as seen below:

> 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, 4A, 4B, 5A, 5B

or

> 1A, 2A, 3A, 4A, 5A, 1B, 2B, 3B, 4B, 5B

The option is configurable by the user via the `loopOrder` variable. The code essentially sets the first loop (`i loop`) or third loop (`k loop`) to 1 to negate it and then sets the other loop to 2.

Code below:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  loopOrder, i, j, k, x, y: integer;
  outputList: array [1 .. 5, 1 .. 2] of string;
begin

  loopOrder := 2; //1 for 1A, 2A, 3A etc. 2 for 1A, 1B, 2A etc.

  for i := 1 to loopOrder do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      x := 2;
      if loopOrder = 2 then
        x := 1;

      for k := 1 to x do
      begin
        if loopOrder = 1 then
          y := k
        else
          y := i;

        if y = 1 then
          outputList[j, y] := inttostr(j) + 'A'
        else
          outputList[j, y] := inttostr(j) + 'B';

        ListBox1.Items.Add(outputList[j, y]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this that perhaps uses less variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak the language you are using so I won't try coding in it, but I would have thought you could simplify the code by something like

```
if loopOrder = 1 then  
    sort by 1st character //x=2 implies k=1 then 2 - unroll for loop
    k=1
    …
    k=2
    …
else
    sort by second character // x=1 implies k=1 - no loop required
    k=1
    …
```

and cut out a lot of testing and variables.
for example x=3-loopOrder //no need for x
hence k is either 1 (when loopOrder=2) or 1 then 2 (when loopOrder=1)
Unroll the for loops as in one case k can only be 1 and in the other just 1 or 2
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since I've used Delphi - great times :) - so consider any code I write as pseudo code.

There are several problems I see here:

It's quite clear what exactly your task or goal here is. You basically speak of "grouping a list", and I first interpreted that as sorting an existing list. However the code is actually creating a list.

Then the structure of the code is quite confusing. You have one single procedure that "does everything", including directly filling the `TListBox`.

This includes the input. Basically everything (the "`loopOrder`", and the structure of the list elements) is hard-coded.

I'd first suggest breaking things down into multiple procedures, especially  just as @PeterJennings suggests, into two procedures for the two variants. Then - if you need it - rewrite to support differently structured lists later.

The input could be changed to something like:

```
const 
    ListStructure: array of array of string = (
        ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
        ('A', 'B')
    );
```